# Is there any function to convert long decimal number in to hexadecimal?

Tags: perl

I have a need to convert a long decimal number :14245138929982432 in to    hexadecimal value whose value is 329BE0DDB29BE0.

But when i am trying to use below piece of code i am getting result as FFFFFFFF.

```
$l_KeyExpected_UL=14245138929982432;
$hexadeci = sprintf '%X', $l_KeyExpected_UL;
print $hexadeci."\n";\
```

can Any one please help on this.

Comment: What version of perl do you use? I've got correct output of '329BE0DDB29BE0' for your script.

Comment: 5_8_9 is the perl version that i am using

Comment: Check my answer below, it should help you.

Comment: @SuneeldattaKolipakula: You should upgrade your installation of perl if you can. v5.8.9 is eight years old now, and you are missing out on major enhancements in v5.10 and v5.14. The latest release is v5.24

Comment: It is the one which was using in my organizations frame work.. I cannot change it but thanks for suggestion....

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [`Math::BigInt`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Math::BigInt) module, which does all the heavy-lifting behind the [`bigint`](https://metacpan.org/pod/bigint) pragma

You can't use `sprintf` under `bigint` to convert large decimals to hex because its conversions aren't overloaded, but `Math::BigInt` objects have an `as_hex` method which returns the number expressed as a hex string, prefixed with `0x`

This program wraps the conversion in a subroutine `bigint_to_hex`, which removes the `0x` prefix and changes lower case to upper case

It is unusual now to encounter an installation of Perl that won't handle 64-bit values anyway. But this method will work with any decimal string, as I have demonstrated by converting a value of 1.2E40 as well as the value in your question

It's vital that you pass big integers as *strings*, because numeric literals will be converted to floating point by the compiler if they exceed the width of an ordinary integer. My program also prints the hex equivalent of the same 1.2E40 value without quotation marks so that you can see the difference

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

use Math::BigInt;


my $l_KeyExpected_UL = '14245138929982432';

say bigint_to_hex($l_KeyExpected_UL);
say bigint_to_hex('12345678901234567890123456789012345678901');
say bigint_to_hex(12345678901234567890123456789012345678901);
say bigint_to_hex(1.2E40);

sub bigint_to_hex {
    my $hex = Math::BigInt->new(shift)->as_hex;
    $hex =~ s/^0x//;
    uc $hex;
}
```

#### output

```
329BE0DDB29BE0
2447DB449988978536BF5BBBE40E766C35
2447DB449988B214BEA48F651CA8000000
2343CBEEEA6F2C193478C00E0000000000
```

Comment: EXCELLENT... IT WORKED :) Thanks friend :)

Comment: @SuneeldattaKolipakula: I'm pleased that I could help. ***Please note*** that you must pass big decimal numbers *as a string* for this to work properly

Answer (score 0):

### If you have a build of Perl with 64-bit integers

A Perl build with 64-bit ints will display the following:

```
$ perl -V:ivsize
ivsize='8';
```

If this is what you have, you can simply use

```
my $i = 14245138929982432;
my $hex = sprintf('%X', $i);
```

### If you have a build of Perl that may not have 64-bit integers

That number requires at least 56 bits to store.

[Math::Int64](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Math::Int64) allows you to access native 64-bit ints.

```
use Math::Int64 qw( uint64 int64_to_hex );

# Note that the number is provided as a string!
my $i = uint64('14245138929982432');
my $hex = int64_to_hex($i);
```

You could also use an arbitrary precision library such as [Math::BigInt](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Math::BigInt), but it will be necessarily slower. If you're going to do some number crunching with 64-bit ints, you definitely want Math::Int64 instead of Math::BigInt.